# Installing build-dep on linux mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I'm trying to install build-dep on Linux mint 15, but I'm getting an error. I've checked my source list and looks fine. I've also updated the system (apt-get update)

This is the command

```
apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

And this is the error:

```
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic'
E: Unable to find a source package for linux
```

And this is my source.list:

```
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb apps games
deb-src http://cran.ms.unimelb.edu.au/bin/linux/ubuntu raring/
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ nadia main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ quantal partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ quantal free non-free

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu quantal-getdeb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the source uri to install the build-dep. Do:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r) # or any other package
```

Comment: When you see it, it is so obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is special. Install `linux-source`; apt-get will default to your current version.

Comment: Then you're done with this step, but the learning curve hardly ends here. Next up, you'll want to install `kernel-package` and read a HOWTO on that.