# install emacs 24.4 error on mint

Tags: linux, emacs

I followed this [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/emacs-24-4-released-install-in-ubuntu-14-04/). But got error, how to fix?

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24
[sudo] password for oracle: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for emacs24

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17 _Qiana_ - Release amd64 20140530]/ trusty contrib main non-free
  deb http://packages.linuxmint.com qiana main upstream import
           deb http://extra.linuxmint.com qiana main
           deb http://mirror.nexcess.net/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
           deb http://mirror.nexcess.net/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
           deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty partner
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from my recipe for Travis CI:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:cassou/emacs
sudo apt-get update -qq
sudo apt-get install -qq emacs24
```

Might be useful.

Comment: but looks like that's for an older version. And i need 24.4

Comment: The dependencies haven't changed probably. You want `build-dep`, right? Not just the executable?

Comment: The answer at this thread is more correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874821/installing-build-dep-on-linux-mint/27510334#27510334

Answer (score 11):

Open the software-sources application, and click "Enable source code repositories"

Then try again.